# How to properly increment variable using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, numpy, anaconda

**Short Version:** I'm trying to increment a variable in mysql table ON DUPLICATE. What happens instead is it only adds new records. The old records remain in-tact, instead of incrementing the sale_date by one. Since this script runs daily, I was trying to just set the sale_date in the mysql database on a duplicate record from yesterday (T-1) to today's shipment_date (T). Any thoughts? Thanks!

```
shipment_date = d.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for index, row in df_main_sql.iterrows():
try:
    command = "INSERT INTO **** (stock_number, sale_date, shipment_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sale_date = shipment_date"
    cursor.execute(command, (row['stock_number'], row['sale_date'], row['shipment_date']))
    connection.commit()
    time.sleep(0.1)
except:
    continue
cursor.close()
```

**Additional Details:** I have a script that runs fine with one exception. I'm trying to write a pandas dataframe to mysql. I run this inventory software for a company, but I have incomplete data based on where we sit in the supply chain. The data basically contains a stock_number, shipment_date, and sale_date. I don't know the sale date, but I can infer that when a new stock_number occurs, it's a new shipment, and when that stock_number is no longer occurring a sale has happened, so I need the program to increment sale_date each day that record occurs, and then do nothing when it stops occurring. That would tell me roughly when new shipments arrive and when they are sold. You have to compare to the existing database, because when the script is run daily, you don't have anyway to know what stock_numbers were not there the day before.

Example of database on day 1

```
stock_number sale_date shipment_date
1234a         06/06/17  06/06/17
1235a         06/06/17  06/06/17
1236a         06/06/17  06/06/17
```

Example of database on day 2 with current script, one new record and no sales

```
stock_number sale_date shipment_date
1234a         06/06/17  06/06/17
1235a         06/06/17  06/06/17
1236a         06/06/17  06/06/17
1237a         06/07/17  06/07/17
```

What should have happened on day 2 if no sales

```
stock_number sale_date shipment_date
1234a         06/07/17  06/06/17
1235a         06/07/17  06/06/17
1236a         06/07/17  06/06/17
1237a         06/07/17  06/07/17
```

Contents of df_main_sql on day 1

```
stock_number sale_date shipment_date
1234a         06/06/17  06/06/17
1235a         06/06/17  06/06/17
1236a         06/06/17  06/06/17
```

Contents of df_main_sql on day 2

```
1234a         06/07/17  06/07/17
1235a         06/07/17  06/07/17
1236a         06/07/17  06/07/17
1237a         06/07/17  06/07/17
```

Comment: What is the unique key of your table ****?

Comment: it's the stock number using variable 'stock_number', that way if it gets the same key or stock number it knows to do something.

Comment: Please give an example of what is happening in the database.

Comment: Added to question. Thanks!

Comment: What is `df_main_sql`. Can you post that?

Comment: Just posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the data correctly to the SQL.

```
...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sale_date = shipment_date"
```

It should be,

```
...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sale_date = %s"
cursor.execute(command, (row['stock_number'], row['sale_date'], row['shipment_date'], shipment_date))
```

Does it help?

Comment: No, now my sale_date on duplicates is 00-00-0000.

Comment: Now the `sale_date` on duplicates is set to 00-00-0000 and no new entry is added?